# Python path problems: Google App Engine SDK and other google modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine, anaconda

`from google.appengine.ext import users` fails.

The crux of my problem is that I have two `google` directories:

One that came with the GAE SDK: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google`

and one that I created when I ran `pip install google-cloud`: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\google`  (this is my default site-packages directory)

The `import` statement above only sees the second directory.  How can I make python aware of the first directory that came with the GAE SDK?

I am developing a project with Google App Engine (GAE); I am using Anaconda and PyCharm

Comment: PYTHONPATH: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: Is this ok if the directories are both named `google`?  if I `import google` after editing the PYTHONPATH, which directory am I getting?

Comment: Also, Anaconda doesn't use PYTHONPATH